# How to go back mentally to running?

Tags: running, running-training-plan

3 Months ago I quit running. I was doing 12km/h for 40 minutes, for a total of 8km, I started running as soft training for my main sport, K1. After summer I started training again and I can't mentally run anymore.

I know that it's not my body, it's my head; it's just stressful. What path should I take to fight this situation?

Comment: Any idea what might be causing this? Personal problems? Lack of motivation? Anxiety?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Mindfulness sounds like it could help. There are many apps and videos out there that offer mindfulness guidance. I personally use the app Headspace (I have no affiliation with them - I am merely a subscriber) - it really helps ground me and make me lose sight of the things that are making me anxious and procrastinate things.

I was very dubious about it before I tried it, and still am to be honest. It is not some miracle cure, but having someone guide your focus can help reorganise your priorities and I think that's what it boils down to for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are two axes of approach I can think of for this. One is to use an interval plan like Couch to 5k so that you have clear intervals. With an app, you'll even be prompted without having to think. The other is to distract yourself from the tedium of the run by listening to something like a podcast, audiobook, or audio drama.

Personally, I combine the two with the [Zombies, Run](https://zombiesrungame.com/) app. In the first season, you get the interval training, interspersed with a fully voice acted drama. Later seasons, it's however you want to run, with further audio drama (although there's an option to turn on "zombie chases" which randomly force you to increase your speed for a time). I know they offer several other "virtual races", often in conjunction with charities.

Answer (score 1):

You could sign up for a race like a 10K or half marathon. A goal usually helps me stay motivated. A training plan will also mix up the types of runs you do which makes it more interesting and also gives each run a purpose (recovery, tempo, sprints, distance, etc).

Another thing to keep in mind is that your body needs a few weeks to get used to running again. After that period running will be much easier and even pleasant.